# refactor a subscription into an observable

Tags: javascript, angular, typescript, rxjs

I am using a method `query_character` to return a promise that makes multiple http-requests. Then I emit that value to a subject `this.search_result$`. This works as expected, but I want to get rid of those ugly embedded subscriptions and return an array of results from the subscription instead.

```
private query_character(query): void {
    this.api.fetch_character_query(query)
    .subscribe( query_responses => {
      query_responses.subscribe( characters => {
        this.search_result$.next( characters )
      });
    })
  }
```

The `fetch_character_query` that is beng called:

```
  public fetch_character_query( query ): any {
    return this.http.get<any>(`some-url`)
    .pipe( map( character_ids => {
      // NOTE:  fetch_character_info returns an Observable
      return character_ids.character.map( character_id => this.fetch_character_info(character_id) ); 
    }))
    .pipe( map( characters => forkJoin( characters ) ) )
  }
```

How can I return an array with results (resolved observables from `this.fetch_character_info`) instead of an array of observables?

Answer (score 1):

```
public fetch_character_query( query ): any {
    return this.http.get<any>(`some-url`)
    .pipe( 
       mergeMap(character_ids => character_ids), //will emit each character id
       mergeMap(id => this.fetch_character_info(character_id).pipe(
           map(res => change into shape you need here),
           catchError(err => handle it)
       ),
       toArray(),
       catchError(err => handle it)
     )
```

https://rxjs.dev/api/operators/toArray

Comment: Very nice. Only suggestion is to use switchMap over mergeMap so existing requests get cancelled when new ones come in. Otherwise I could see some interesting race conditions happening.

Comment: Can you elaborate what the first `mergeMap` does? My understanding is that it turns an array of promises in an array of the results of these promises. You seem to be using it as if it is a `from` operator.

Comment: Yup. It flattens the array into it's individual items, emitting each one.